# Does using ?: to do an assignment produce faster assembly than using if()?

Tags: objective-c, c, performance, compilation, ternary-operator

I'd like to know which one of the following two forms of lazy instantiation generates faster assembly code. Here's the code:

**1st:**

```
if (!_separatorTopBorderColor) _separatorTopBorderColor = UIColorFromHex(0x393A3B);
return _separatorTopBorderColor;
```

**2nd:**

```
_separatorTopBorderColor = _separatorTopBorderColor ?: UIColorFromHex(0x393A3B);
return _separatorTopBorderColor;
```

Comment: If there's any performance difference, your compiler is Doing It Wrong. I can't say that no hideously wrong/evil compiler exists in the world, but certainly none that you ought to be using.

Comment: Note that `?:` (with no expression in the middle) is not valid C.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might be an issue 10 years ago, but nowadays, compilers literally sees any difference with `ternary` operators and `if-else` statements. My advise is that you should concentrate on keeping your code more readable, maintainable, and efficient. Don't care about resource or memory usage in this case.

Comment: I doubt it was an issue even for the very first C compiler. The abstract syntax tree would very likely be **identical** to that of an if/else.

Comment: Thank you! I just wanted to be sure.

Answer (score 1):

This is really a question of ternary operators vs regular if-statements. Neither will be faster, so it's really a matter of aesthetics/preference.

Answer (score 1):

No. Simple as that. And why should it.

Answer (score 0):

Well, choose whichever is more readable.

Now, from a compiler optimization perspective, most optimizing compilers contain an optimizer pass called "if-conversion" or something like that, which is a pass which can convert a SIMPLE branch into a conditional move instruction. In your case you have a function call right there in one of the branches, so this doesn't matter. Secondly, on a superscalar OoO processor with decent branch prediction, conditional moves are in most cases a pessimization compared to a simple branch, so in fact compilers targeting such CPU's will most likely not do the if-conversion.